# promise returning request to get `idToken`

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

Looking at this snippet I have a doubt. If I want to pass `idToken` with every request to my backend server, do I have make this request every time and resolve that promise always? Or can I get `idToken` once user logs in and then store it somewhere in my js context and reuse it on following request to backend server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getIdToken will get the current token and only refresh the token if it is expired, see more here

[Firebase Reference: getIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken)

> Returns a JWT token used to identify the user to a Firebase service.
>
> Returns the current token if it has not expired, otherwise this will
>   refresh the token and return a new one.

Comment: I see that. But my question is whether it's the same to extract that token from localStorage(called accessToken there) or to make getIdToken request always?

Comment: getIdToken already keeps the token for you locally, no need to do that yourself. So yes use getIdToken before every request as it also makes sure to refresh the token if needed.

Comment: Do not manipulate `localStorage` to get these values. You will break things and Firebase Auth has the right to change how state is persisted. Firebase Auth gives you easy APIs to do so, as Kim suggested.